# Gradle not found when using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, hybrid-mobile-app

I recently reinstalled Android Studio and I get this message now when running "cordova build android"

```
D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local

\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://gradle.org/install/#helpful-information
I follow the steps and I could install gradle